# Okular text annotations Mutated vowels

Tags: okular

I'm using Kubuntu 21.04
Okular(Version 20.12.3) doesn't display german mutated vowels (ä,ö,ü) in text annotations.
Maybe somebody could help me. Thanks in advance.